# Does strictly convex imply invertible gradient?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis, inverse, inverse-function, scalar-fields

If $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ is strictly convex and continuously differentiable, does this imply that $\nabla f$ is a one-to-one mapping? To be precise, can we say that $x, y \in \mathbb R^n$ and $\nabla f(x) = \nabla f(y)$ implies $x = y$?

Comment: in 1D yes, it means the derivative is strictly increasing. so if you can reduce the $n$ dimensional case to the $n-1$ dimensional case, it will be proved.

Comment: Just to add on the "1D is enough" idea. If $\nabla f(x)=\nabla f(y)$, we can take $g(t)= f(x + t(y-x))$, which will be strictly convex $\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ function, and using the chain rule $g'(0)=g'(1)$, which gets us to the 1D case (I hope I'm not overlooking something)

Comment: The OP addresses this down below in a comment to an answer, but in case anyone else is wondering, we only learn here that $\nabla f$ is injective, not that it is bijective. I'm tempted to change the title to reflect this, but I don't want to micromanage the OP's post.

Answer (score 16):

Suppose that there exist $x, y \in \mathbb R^n$ such that $\nabla f(x) = \nabla f(y)$ and $x \neq y$.

Then, by the strict convexity of $f$, we can write
\begin{equation}
\nabla f(x) \cdot (y-x) < f(y) - f(x)
\end{equation}
and similarly
\begin{equation}
\nabla f(y) \cdot (x-y) < f(x) - f(y).
\end{equation}
Multiplying both sides of the latter inequality by $-1$ and substituting $\nabla f(x)$ in place of $\nabla f(y)$, we obtain
\begin{equation}
\nabla f(x) \cdot (y - x) > f(y) - f(x),
\end{equation}
which contradicts the first inequality.

Thus, if $x, y \in \mathbb R^n$ satisfy $\nabla f(x) = \nabla f(y)$, then $x =y$.

Comment: yes, this works

Answer (score 0):

This question has a big intersection with an answer of mine to a [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/105912/equivalence-between-hamiltonian-and-lagrangian-mechanics) in Physics Stack Exchange concerning the equivalence of the Lagrangian and Hamiltonian formalism. Actually there my resoning was a bit different regarding the hypotheses.

In that case $f$ was the Lagrangian function with $t, q$ fixed, as function of $\dot{q}$. I write down here  my idea referred to that setup.

One can conclude  a little more than what was requested in the original issue if assuming that

- $f$ is $C^2$,
- relaxing the hypothesis on the domain by supposing that $f: A \to \mathbb{R}$ with $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is **open** and **convex**.
- $f$ is **convex**.

Saying that $f$ is a $C^2$ **convex function** I mean above that the Hessian matrix  $$H(x) = \left[\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} \right]$$
is **everywhere positively defined** on its domain $A$.

We can prove that, under the three hypothes above,

(1) $B:= \nabla f(A) \subset \mathbb{R}$ is open;

(2)
$$F: A \ni x \mapsto \nabla f(x) \in B$$
is a $C^1$ diffeomorphism.

In fact, as I prove below $F$ satisfy $dF \neq 0$ in $A$, so that the inverse map theorem proves that  $F$ is a local $C^1$- diffeomorphism. In particular $F$ is *open* and thus $B$ is open as well. Since, as I also prove below,  $F$ is also injective, it is a $C^1$ diffeomorphism from $A$ to $B$.

*Proof of $dF \neq 0$*. If $dF(x_0)=0$, then $dF(x_0) X=0$ for every $X\in \mathbb{R}^n$, that is
$H(x_0)X =0$ and thus $X^t H(x_0) X =0$, in particular  for some  $X\neq 0$. This is in contraddiction with the fact that $H(x)$ is everywhere positively defined.

*Proof of injectivity of $F$*.  If $F(x)=F(y)$, and $x\neq y$, consider the segment
$z(t) = x + t (y-x)$ for $t\in [0,1]$ which is completely included in $A$ it being convex, and define the $C^1$ map $$[0,1]\ni t \mapsto (y-x)^t F(z(t)) \in \mathbb{R}.$$ It holds
$(y-x)^t F(z(1))= (y-x)^t F(z(0))$
and thus
$\frac{d (x-y)^t F(z(t))}{dt}|_{t_0}=0$ for some $t \in (0,1)$. That is
$$t_0(x-y)^t dF(z(t_0))(y-x)=0 $$
and thus
$$(y-x)^t H(z(t_0))(y-x) = (y-x)^t dF(z(t_0))(y-x)=0$$
which is impossible as before since $y-x \neq 0$.

Answer (score -3):

No. Try $x \mapsto \mathrm{e}^x$.

Comment: but $\nabla f=e^x$ is invertible, is it not?

Comment: I think the confusion is that I was using the term "invertible" loosely.  I meant, "invertible on the range of $\nabla f$.  I have reworded the question in a way that will hopefully clear things up.

Comment: Imho, this definition of "invertible" is quite unusual (and impractical).